# How is the backward propagation is done in pytroch? When to use torch.no_grad, also when and where is the gradinte calcuated?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I have this training loop in pytorch. the `loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` and `optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)`

```
    for X, y in train_dataloader:
        X = X.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)

        optim.zero_grad()

        pred = net(X)

        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        train_loss += loss.item() * X.size(0)
        pred = torch.argmax(pred, dim= -1)
        train_correct += (pred == y).float().sum()

        with torch.no_grad():
            loss.backward()
            optim.step()
```

now it works fine and the model runs well and gets an accuarcy of 0.99. My question is why does loss.backward() work if `with torch.no_grad` should make it not possible to calculate the gradient of the trainable weights. And if `with torch.no_grad()` was not there would it be the exact same training loop and possibly output the same output. I understand that `optim.step()` doesn't change the gradient right? But subtracts the gradient from the weights. So why use `with torch.no_grad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the forum.
How is backward propagation done in pytorch? I would refer you to this: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html for a complete overview, but the short version is, pytorch will create a computational graph and differentiate according to the chain rule. Note that there are three "modes" mentioned - default mode (grad mode), no-grad mode, and inference mode.

When to use with torch.no_grad()? In general when you'd like to do something to the parameters without impacting future computations of the gradients. For training, you generally don't want or need torch.no_grad(). For inference you'd generally want to use inference mode, which speeds up computation.

As you note, optim.step() doesn't change the gradient, because optimizers in pytorch are decorated with (@torch.no_grad()) for the step method.

For the last part, you're computing your loss function outside of the no_grad block. You can see this still works by printing your parameters as they are updated, e.g. something like this in your training loop:

```
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
with torch.no_grad():
    if param.requires_grad:
        print (name, param.data)
```